# How to comment intelligently in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I know how to make a comment intelligently by customizing live templates in PyCharm, it shows like below:

```python
###################### Notion #######################
##################### Wating Time ########################
##################### order ########################
```

whenever I type `#` and click `Tab`, it will show

```python
####################   ######################
```

I just type in the middle, but the problem is that each time I type in the middle, the length of phase is not equal (like the first set of code), I want to realize such function, that's

```python
###################### Notion #######################
##################### Wating Time ###################
##################### order logit ###################
```

you can notice that, the right side of those three lines are aligned no matter what I typed, the length is the same and they are symmetric. Is PyCharm able to make it?

Comment: Please don't use that kind of comments. It adds a lot of noise and distraction. Instead, use `# region` and `# endregion`, and it will even let you fold that block. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163245/how-to-make-section-in-pycharm/55163293#55163293

Comment: *"Is PyCharm able to make it?"* Using  Live Templates -- No (as it cannot change already entered static text). Maybe using some custom plugin... But the best option is to use short comments with minimal `###` at the start and the end; even better -- look at the comment above.